# Making a machine from scratch

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

Let's assume I want to build, for example, a coffee machine with a special twist from scratch.

I guess I would need plans, mechanical evaluations, CAO, then machining or 3D printing. I also guess I would need to interface my mechanical parts with some electronics to control flow or some more specific gear.

So my question is: what is the general procedure about this ?

Which knowledge do I need to learn/know ?

Comment: Somehow the only thing that comes to mind is the Monty Python sketch about "how to play the flute."   You are asking questions that have no answers other than "go to school and learn science and math."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Nicely put.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't know the sketch you are talking about, but if you asked me the question in the way I intended (maybe I really wasn't clear) I would have answered "learn solfege, then learn how notes are played on the flutes, then practice". I do know a bit of science and math, however I wonder how do someone build a machine such as coffee machine from scratch.

Comment: If I would be to give an example. Q:'How do we make medicine drugs and what knowledge do you need ?' A:'You need to know about organic chemistry for most drugs, biochemistry and a bit of biology for some of them. In the lab, you then have to think carefully on reactions you need to setup from standard chemicals in order to achieve your specific drug'.

Comment: @Blue_Elephant The problem is that the answer to your "making drugs" example is so vague that for practical purposes it is useless. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNfGyIW7aHM.

Comment: FYI here is an example of answer I was vainly expecting to get [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-design-a-machine) or [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-basic-concepts-of-machine-design). Sorry if I wasn't clear enough or if it doesn't fit in the general scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Studying engineering or a course on practical design would be a good start.

The "general procedure" is "design-build-redesign" (or just design-build if you intend for this to be a 1-off).

There's no real good answer to this, the design process is complicated and not standard, you can follow many different methods to design.

The knowledge you need to learn and know will be whatever you don't know when you try and design and build this.  There are numerous areas where you will likely have to learn this; but this depends *entirely* on what your current level of understanding is.  It could be as easy as reading some chapters from a few textbooks.

It's more likely that you could spend years looking into the design if you wanted to, optimizing and iterating as you learn more.  You could make your design very precise, or have everything loosely controlled for less consistent results.

**TL;DR** What you would need to know are all the things that are currently preventing you from building this.  There is no easy answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Can you tell me some of the few textbooks you mentioned ?